# Batch add column to layers and add layer prefix in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, batch

I have a number of layers each with a prefix like A_ B_ and so forth.

I'd like to:

1. Add a column (text) called DENSITY to each shp
2. Add the prefix letter from the layer name to each row in the DENSITY column for each shp file.

Can it be done?

I'm using QGIS 2.8.1

---

Update:

I think there was a typo here with a missing `+`

```
print "- layer: " child.layerName() + "  ID: " + child.layerId()
```

and I ran this:

```
# Iterate through the Legend to find all groups and layers
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

for child in root.children(): 
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    print "- group: " + child.name()

# If we find a group, save the prefix name

    prefix = group.name().split('_')[0]
    elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
    print "- layer: " + child.layerName() + "  ID: " + child.layerId()
    layer = child.layer()

# Add code to add a field named density to the layer.
#######
# Add code to iterate through each feature in the layer and populate the field with prefix value
#######
```

but got these errors:

> line 4, in 
>       root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
>   AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'layerTreeRoot'

[image: Image if split files:]

Comment: Do you want to do this a automated way or a manual approach will work? It's quite simple to do this manually, but doing it in bulk will require some scripting.

Comment: Hi. Manually i can do but having 100+ shp files it would be a good excercise to start looking into scripting.

Comment: Your first task can be done using the Model Builder from the _Processing Toolbox_ and using the **Field Calculator** algorithm to add a new field. When you save this model, you can right-click on it and run it as a batch process. I agree with @spatialthoughts that for your second task, there will be some scripting involved which you can add to your Model using the **Advanced Python field calculator** algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by running the following code snippet in the QGIS Python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    prefix = layer.name().split("_")[0]
    res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("density", QVariant.String)])
    layer.updateFields()
    fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( "density" )
    attrFeatMap = {}
    attrMap = { fieldIndex : prefix }
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        attrFeatMap[ feature.id() ] = attrMap
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

I assume the only layers you have loaded in the QGIS ToC are those you want to modify. Otherwise, you would need to validate things like the layer type (i.e., you don't want the script to run on raster layers).

The script iterates through layers loaded into QGIS, extracts the prefix from their names, creates the text field `density`, builds a dictionary like this:

```
{ featureId : { fieldIndex : value } }
```

for each feature, and finally, applies the dictionary to change features' density values.

[image]

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Hi.

I tried the above and got this...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterDataProvider' object has no attribute 'addAttributes'

Comment: Ok. My fault here. It was actually working. I had two layers of polygons loaded which arrested the script from running.

Thanks alo.

Comment: As I told you in the answer, if you have other layers loaded in QGIS, you need to filter them out (e.g., via an if like: `if layer.type() == 0:` right below the `for` line).

Comment: Hi. I seem to have a problem with the above after all.

I have split a vector shape file by features and have got several vector shape files.

Running the script gives me the prefix of the original shape file that i split and not the prefix of the split files.

I may have to include a "for each group" after all?

Comment: Much easier if you just tell us how your layer names look like now and how do you want your layer names to be after running the script. Otherwise, every time you change the original scenario, the solution won't apply anymore.

Comment: True. I found that I had to split layers by field and move the added layers outside the groups, run the script. Worked fine then. I was just not aware of that running a batch using the split vector layer by attribute only made a virtual separation of the shape file and not physical layers.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have about 50 shapefiles each with up to 20 attributes. I would like to batch-add to each of the shapefiles an attribute column containing the name of the respective shapefile (or even better if possible: of the group in which the layer is located). I am a noob with python.

Comment: @HannesLedegen, you should open a new question in GIS.SE.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I can point you to code snippets and resources to help you get to your goal.

[PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) is a great place to look if you are just getting started with scripting.

First you need to iterate through the groups and layers. [This is a good reference for it](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/). You can do something like

```
# Iterate through the Legend to find all groups and layers
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children(): 
  if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    print "- group: " + child.name()
    # If we find a group, save the prefix name
    prefix = group.name().split('_')[0]
  elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
    print "- layer: " child.layerName() + "  ID: " + child.layerId()
    layer = child.layer()
    # Add code to add a field named density to the layer.
    #######
    # Add code to iterate through each feature in the layer and populate the field with prefix value
    #######
```

You will find the code snippets to add a field is at [Adding and Removing Fields](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#adding-and-removing-fields)

And snippet for iterating through the features is at [Iterating over Vector Layer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer)

Comment: OK.This sounds great and i will have something to dive into. I keep you posted...

Comment: The last section regarding iteration. Maybe it's me but i fail to see why it should go through each feature in the layers unless that means "every row"

Comment: Ok. This is a bit out of my league.  cant get it to run...

Comment: Hi.I tried this: